# Should I have my bath vanity drain augered to eliminate odor and dampness?

Tags: plumbing, drain

The drains on our master bathroom look like they drain properly, but there's at least a hint that something's wrong: whenever we use mouthwash, the smell of mint sticks in the master bathroom and invades the master bedroom for many minutes afterwards.

The bathroom also often acquires a vaguely damp smell (though there is no fan, and we live in a humid area, so it may simply be damp).

Is there anything we should consider doing before putting money into having a plumber come out and looking at the drains? (We've tried a couple of obvious simple things like baking soda and vinegar down the drains, and Liquid Plumr/Drano.)

Comment: Are you flushing the used mouthwash down the drain with some tap water? Bathrooms are damp even with exhaust fans. Your expectations may be askew. It doesn't sound like there's a problem here to me.

Comment: Also, does any other product result in lingering odor? Maybe it's just a very effervescent mouthwash (possibly containing highly-evaporative alcohol).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's worth saying, this all represents a change (from our previous bathrooms -- this is a house to which we've moved recently). For instance flushing mouthwash with water from the tap was never previously necessary to avoid lingering smells. So, that's what sets my expectations. Certainly that's something we're getting in the habit of doing here.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @isherwood+  The P trap holds some water to prevent sewer gasses from entering the home (all drains have them some times called a U bend). After rinsing your mouth, run the water for a bit to flush the mouthwash down the drain and the smell will be gone.